# How to preview XAML of ControlTemplate design in Visual Studio for WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, controltemplate

When designing XAML for WPF application, Visual Studio shows a generated preview design next to the XAML code editor.

However, the 'design' panel doesn't show the preview if the XAML code is in the '`Template`' node, for example, `ControlTemplate`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ListTitle}" /> <!-- IDE doesn't initially provide how this element will look like -->
...
</ControlTemplate>
```

There are a bunch of things inside such a `ControlTemplate` node, yet I have to code XAML without any preview, just relying on my estimation. Then, run the application each time to see how these XAML codes actually are being designed.

Is there a way to 'preview' the design of XAML inside `ControlTemplate` node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you can use XAML Hot Reload, so you run your application, change and save your xaml code and see the changes simultaneously.

To enable XAML Hot Reload, go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> XAML Hot Reload -> Enable XAML Hot Reload in Visual Studio 2022. In Visual Studio 2019, it's almost the same, I believe it's in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Hot Reload. More detail on XAML Hot Reload [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload?view=vs-2022).

Comment: Thanks for introducing a better way. Is there any kind of 'instant preview' like feature in the VS? I just quickly see how the XAML code will look without running the application and inefficiently get to the proper Window step by step. Do most industrial WPF developers test their XAML code design like this?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your solution after the changes?

Comment: that's not what I mean. The suggested Hot Reload is working, while I just want to know even if there is a simpler way, without Run or Hot Reload.

Comment: @klados If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)
 It's hard for us to find a better way for the time being.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFTNo, I haven't found the solution. The solution above is like an alternative one.

Comment: @klados there's no better solution out there (at least not that I know of). But what you could do is change your application for the time being and set the window as a startup window so that you can preview your changes without navigating to that specific window. I know it kinda sucks but as far as XAML preview choices go, I haven't found any alternative way of doing it either.

Comment: @drazse okay. thanks. In Xcode and Android Studio, such virtual 'Item Elements' can be directly drawn in the preview pane so that I can make even slight changes on a real-time basis. I think it would be great to see similar features in VS IDE in future updates.

Comment: I think I finally figured out your question. You create control templates in resource dictionaries and that's why you say you can't preview it. All you have to do is to apply this control template for that specific control, and your control (let's say on a user control) will change according to your control template changes and you can actually preview it because it is a user control.